# How to do i get rid of this error "network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory" on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet, weave, calico, cni

I uninstalled calico using:
'kubectl delete -f calico.yaml'

and installed weave using:
'export kubever=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')'
'kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$kubever"'

When i deploy my pods they remain at "ContainerCreating" status.
When i check pod logs i see error below:

'networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "saccofrontend-d7444fd6d-998gf_default" network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory: check that the calico/node container is running and has mounted /var/lib/calico/'

I manually deleted this file.
A reinstall of docker and kubeadm did not help either.Still getting the same error.

Please advise what could be promting kubelet to still use calico as the cni even though i unstialled it.

Comment: have you tried deleting /etc/cni/net.d directory before installing weave?

Comment: Hi, what k8s version do You have? Also what platform and infrastructure do You use?

Comment: Running v1.18.0 on Centos 8.One master and two workers.

Comment: I will try deleting the /etc/cni/net.d directory before installing weave tomorrow morning and see if that will solve the issue.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

thank you for pointing me in the right direction: These cmds solved the problem:
rm -rf /var/lib/cni
rm -rf /etc/cni/net.d

then re-installed kubeadm

Answer (score 3):

My issue was that I was using the command below to setup the Calico CNI:

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.9/manifests/calico.yaml
```

Using the link below instead worked. It's the same without the version I guess.

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

**Install Tigera Operator**

```
kubectl create -f https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/manifests/tigera-operator.yaml
```

**Install Calico by creating the necessary custom resource**

```
kubectl create -f https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/manifests/custom-resources.yaml
```

Now Watch the nodes running and bring up core dns pod too.